# How to get HTML page content using Mink with PhantomJS?

Tags: symfony, phantomjs, behat, mink

Using the Goutte driver with Behat / Mink, I could get the page content in a feature context method like this:

```
$this->getSession()->visit('/blog');
$html = $this->getSession()->getPage()->getHtml()
```

But now that I am using the Selenium2 driver with PhantomJS, the `$html` variable only contains the following text:

```
<head></head><body></body>
```

Did I miss a parameter (like the base URL for instance)?

Here is my `behat.yml` configuration:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: 'http://localhost:8000'
            selenium2:
                wd_host: "http://localhost:8643/wd/hub"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it's always the same: I looked for the solution for hours before asking here, but I found the solution just a few minutes later after asking.

So it was indeed a problem with the base URL.

The generic way to call the `visit` method is the following:

```
$this->getSession()->visit($this->locatePath('/blog'))
```

The `locatePath` method is used to retrieve the base URL and is used for `Given I am on <page>`.